# Implementation of a kotlin function

Tags: java, kotlin

Trying to implement this function  `fun <E> intersection(list1: Node<E>, list2: Node<E>, cmp: Comparator<E>): Node<E> {}`

given the doubly linked, circular, sentinel lists referenced by list1 and list2, and
sorted in ascending order according to the cmp comparator, returns a list with the elements that
are simultaneously present in list1 and list2, removing them in both lists. the list returned
should be doubly linked, non-circular and without sentinel, sorted in ascending order. must still
reuse the nodes of one of the lists (list1 or list2) and cannot contain repeated elements..

Node implementation :

```
class Node<E> {
    var previous: Node<E>? = null
    var next: Node<E>? = null
    var value: E? = null
}
```

I ve been on this problem for like 2 days. i really cant grasp what ive been doing wrong.
I would be really grateful if someone could help me

this is what i have so far , i can return the right values of the new List , but cant delete the nodes in list1 and list2 without ruining the iteration of the loops

```
fun <E> intersection(list1: Node<E>, list2: Node<E>, cmp: Comparator<E>): Node<E>? {
    //var arrayList =ArrayList<Node<E>>()
    var arr = ArrayList<E?>()
    var list: Node<E>? = null
    var temp = list1
    var temp2 = list2
    var count = 0
    var head : Node<E>? = null
    while (temp.next?.value != null){
        temp = temp.next!!

        while(temp2.next?.value !=null){
            temp2 = temp2.next!!
            if(cmp.compare(temp.value,temp2.value)==0 && !arr.contains(temp.value)){


                var novo = temp


                if (list != null){
                    novo.previous = list
                    list.next = novo
                }
                list = novo

                count ++
                if(count==1){
                    list.previous = null
                    head = list
                }

                arr.add(temp.value)
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: *...i really cant grasp what ive been doing wrong...* Well, what are you doing and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you explain what you need to do, step by step, before you try coding anything? If you can outline the algorithm (for yourself, I'm not telling you to post it necessarily!) then it'll be a lot easier to follow that recipe when you come to implement it. And it'll be easier to tell where things are going wrong, and what you're having trouble with specifically

Comment: @cactustictacs ive managed to do it. Finally! PAssed all unit tests god bless. Thanks for the words. Your words helped. took a step back and remade it

Comment: @Kripthonite that's awesome, congrats! For me stepping away from the computer helps a lot, and writing on paper to work stuff out - if you find out what works for you, you'll be able to take on bigger challenges and solve all kinds of problems in a way you're happy with. So seriously, great job working through it yourself! ✊

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <E> intersection(list1: Node<E>, list2: Node<E>, cmp: Comparator<E>): Node<E>? {
//var arrayList =ArrayList<Node<E>>()

var list: Node<E>? = null
var temp = list1
var temp2 = list2
var count = 0
var head : Node<E>? = null
while (temp.next?.value != null){
    temp = temp.next!!

    while(temp2.next?.value !=null){
        temp2 = temp2.next!!
        if(cmp.compare(temp.value,temp2.value)==0 ){
            var novo = deleteNode(temp)
            if (list != null){
                novo.previous = list
                list.next = novo
            }
            list = novo
            count ++
            if(count==1){
                list.previous = null
                head = list
            }

            deleteNode(temp2)
            break;
        }

    }
    temp2 = list2

}


return head}




fun <E> deleteNode(node : Node<E>): Node<E>{

var prev = node.previous
var next = node.next
//var temp = node

while(next!=null && next!!.value == node.value ){ // eliminado duplicados
    next = next.next
    //temp = temp.next!!
}


if (prev != null) {
    prev.next = next
}
if (next != null) {
    next.previous = prev
}

return node}
```

Here is the resolution to my own problem. This was a headache. Hope this helps someone